# Using pygit2's discover_repository to locate multiple repositories in a directory

Tags: git, python-3.x, git-bare, pygit2

I have a project in which I need to access a (local) directory of bare git repositories in order to get specific items from their history. I need a function which will iterate through the directory and do something like:

```
repo = pygit2.discover_repository("/path/to/repo")
```

but I need to be able to do this in a `for` loop.

Each of the repositories is for a different project, the names of which are located and stored in a list through the use of some nested loops elsewhere in my code.

1) Does it make sense to use the project names in place of `repo` above if I will only be referencing the project names based on their list index throughout my code (or should I instead give each repo a name like `repo_n` where n is an integer that gets incremented in each iteration of the loop that discovers the repos)?

2) Is it possible to discover these repos in a `for` loop so that I can get them all in one go, or will I need to do them one by one?

3) If it *is* possible to do this in a loop, how can I go about creating a tuple (or maybe a dictionary) that contains the project name and the newly discovered repository object?

Comment: I would very much like to know why my question was downvoted so that I may improve it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I had started with code like the following:

```
name = 'repo_'
i = 0
repo_list = {}
items = get_items() # defined elsewhere

for item in os.listdir(dirpath):
    i = i + 1 # this was just to add a custom name to the repos located
    repo_name = name + str(i)
    path_to_repo = os.path.join(dirpath, item)

    repo = pygit2.discover_repository(path_to_repo)
    repo_list[item] = repo
```

but this was returning a list of `string` objects instead of a list of `Repository` objects. It turned out that the `discover_repository()` function returns the *path* to the repository, not the Repository object. I have to say, I didn't find a `discover_repository()` function anywhere in the [pygit2 documentation](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html), and I hadn't seen anyone use or talk about it until I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460143/difference-between-no-branch-and-detached-at-abc1234). But now I know (and I think it'll be useful for future readers as well):

> pygit2's `discover_repository(path)` function returns a string representation of the path to the located repository. This is not a Repository object, which still must be instantiated.

So after looking everywhere for an answer, I found [this snippet](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/230266/A-trivial-script-to-visualise-a-git-hist), which included a line I'd missed:

```
    path_to_repo = os.path.join(dirpath, item)

    repo = pygit2.discover_repository(path_to_repo)
    repo_name = Repository(repo) # this line was missing
    repo_list[item] = repo_name
```

Closer, but something's off here. Sure, this does what I wanted, but isn't that a little redundant? Later, after working on a different section of my code, I ended up with just this as my whole `for` loop:

```
for item in os.listdir(dirpath):
    i = i + 1
    repo_name = name+str(i)
    path_to_repo = os.path.join(dirpath, item)

    repo_name = Repository(path_to_repo)
    repo_list[item] = repo_name
```

This achieves the desired result. I now have a dictionary returned that looks something like:

```
{'repo_1': [listOfRepositoryObjects], 'repo_2': [anotherListOfRepositoryObjects]}
```

So I actually didn't need the `pygit2.discover_repository()` function at all, because I included something which does the same thing at `path_to_repo = os.path.join(dirpath, item)`. Since they ended up returning the same thing, I'm going with the function I wrote because it seems to fit better with my project's requirements.